# Best way to wake a sleeping thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, events, sleep

There's an instrument on my LAN that sends a UDP data packet every 5-10 ms.  In my application, I have a reader thread that allocates a socket with a large buffer when it starts, then enters an infinite loop to read the accumulated packets, parse them, write them to a spooler, then sleep for half a second (`time.sleep(0.500)`).

I have several lazy consumers for the data, most of which do archiving or generate passive statistics.  But one consumer (for display) needs up-to-the-moment data, and needs to wake the sleeping reader (to read the socket) before querying the spooler.

What is the best way to wake a sleeping thread?

(Or, alternately, is there a better way for a thread to sleep that's easier to wake?)

Comment: Why do you need to sleep at all?

Comment: Because it is more efficient to do so.

Comment: @BobC: It is typically even more efficient to *wait* for the actual event to happen and not to *poll* regularly whether the event already happened. E.g. using `select` to wait for file descriptor activity. https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html

Comment: @MarcelWaldvogel: `select` is not available on all OSs.

Comment: Python `select` is exposed on all Unix/POSIX-ish OSes and *for sockets* also on Windows. So, in a network context, it is available on "all" OSes. If it is just timeout/notify, as the answer suggests, then there is no need for `select`. (And if you need [`select` and signals, there is `pselect()`](https://netfuture.ch/2016/02/pselect-pitfalls/) or [`signalfd()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), of course only on POSIX or Linux, respectively.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had failed to notice that threading.condition.wait() has an optional timeout argument!

The answer is to [create a condition object](https://web.archive.org/web/20200319103023/http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) and use its [wait()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.wait) method with the optional timeout instead of [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep).  If the thread needs to be woken prior to the timeout, call the [notify()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.notify) method of the condition object.